# What is the reason for this strange PHP behaviour?

Tags: php, arrays, types

I have the following code:

```
$data = array(); // prep array
$data['aardvark'] = true;

print_r($data); // output array
echo "\n";
var_dump(in_array('zebra', $data));
```

The output is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [aardvark] => 1
)

bool(true)
```

Despite the fact that `zebra` is clearly not in the array. It looks like it's to do with PHP's loose type system. `(bool) 'zebra'` is `true`, and there's a `true` in the array so the `in_array` returns true?

I think I can see the logic, but it's flawed. Is this a PHP bug?

Cheers.

Comment: don't know if it'll help, but you can use array_key_exists to search in the keys of the array

Comment: Anytime you put true, false, 0, or 1 in an array, `in_array()` becomes basically useless unless you specify to use strict comparison.

Comment: @animuson: Of course you can have arrays with numeric values, so where is `0` or `1` useless in conjunction with `in_array()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug. You have it exactly right. To correctly find what you are looking for, you will have to do this:

```
if (in_array('zebra', $data, true)) {
```

Although this would probably be rare that you store different data types in the same array (strings and booleans). If you are storing data that are not a list, you should most likely be using an object instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in-array)

> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

You must set the third parameter to `true`, if you want `in_array()` to test against the type too. Otherwise it will make loose comparison

```
var_dump(in_array('zebra', $data, true));
```

Usually this is no problem, because (in a clean design) usually all values are of the same type you know before you call `in_array()` and thus you can avoid calling it with mismatching types.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the string `'zebra'` is non-empty and a non-empty string other than `'0'` is interpreted by PHP as `true` and since there is a matching value in your array you get `true` as result.

PHP did a conversion from string to boolean. To avoid this conversion you need to pass a third argument as `true` to `in_array`:

```
var_dump(in_array('zebra', $data, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature!" =)

Try doing `in_array("zebra", $data, true);` which will force "strict" checking (i.e. it will do a type-check on your variables).